# connector for 25Amps

Tags: connector

I am using the OSTT7020150  connector for my board. 
This connector has capability to connect wires 10-25AWG which means it can tolerate about 25Amps(from the AWG chart). Now, when designing the board, I have seperate planes for both Vcc and GND. But, my doubt is regarding the drill dia and the solder masking.
Pls see the picture below of the board with the connector(i am showing the bottom view).

[image]

It shows the VBAT (VCC) and GND. But can such a small drill be sufficient to pass 25Amps. I am a bit surprised. Can you advice me on this. Also, is it suggested that I keep that area solder mask free so as to let out heat and help in heat dissipation. Kindly advice me please.

Comment: This is not a design that I would use for 25A.

Comment: That terminal block is apparently rated for 30A by the manufacturer - although I wouldn't feel comfortable using it for much more than 10-ish. However your PCB doesn't seem (from the pic you've shown us) to be routed with anywhere near those sorts of currents in mind.

Comment: I have inner VCC and GND layers. Why do you say its not a design for 25AMps pls. can you please elaborate.

Comment: Oh. The thin tracks are not VCC and GND. I have dedicated planes for the VCC and GND(inner planes). Also, I have GND pours and also VCC pours on both top and bottom layer.

Comment: WHat is the actual drill diameter? Why are you concerned that the solder mask could affect the ampacity?

Comment: the drill is about 3mm or so. Its as recommended in the connector datasheet. But somehow the connector does not give me enough confidence. I have a 1oz Cu weight. If I go for 2oz I guess it will help me.
The reason for the solder mask is I have seen boards with exposed copper. So I thought they would dissipate heat more effectively. Can anyone point me to high current board design please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your decision to route that amount of power using an internal layer is poor choice IMO. From what I understand, the via in which the component lead is seated, is the bottleneck connection.

Please excuse the crudeness of the following depiction - I tried to emphasize how soldering through-hole leads on outer layers makes sense. It allows larger mass of solder to be in the way of current, therefore decreases resistance.

*(Amount of arrows indicates current cross section/conductance)*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fldfsc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There's one more thing to consider. It's not always guaranteed, that your plated holes will be 100% filled with solder. In such case, the situation is even worse, as the currents have to travel up and down the via's plating.

---

Bottom line is:

Solder high-current leads to outer layers and if needed, provide heavy via stitching to a layer of choice afterwards.

Comment: I have some pours on the top and bottom as well for the VCC and GND.These I am stiching to the internal layers using many VIAs.

Comment: so what do you suggest I do just solder wires to the board with large PADs.

Comment: @VinodKaruvat You can perhaps show the places where you do this via stitching. Because the image you posted shows no such thing.